# Using Hyperlinks in protected cells when users cannot select locked cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, hyperlink

In an excel 2013 spreadsheet, I have an =Hyperlink formula to generate a dynamic hyperlink that changes based on a drop down list.  I want to protect this sheet and restrict the user from selecting locked cells (which includes the cells with a hyperlink)

the problem:

- if I restrict the user from selecting locked cells by unchecking the "select locked cells" box, the hyperlink does not work.  you can click, but nothing happens
- If I allow the user to select locked cells, they have to deal with
  that annoying pop up message whenever they accidentally hit a key
- If i unlock the hyperlink cells, the formula is vulnerable.  Also, if
  a hyperlink cell is selected and the user clicks on a locked cell (i.e. anywhere else on the screen),
  they activate the hyperlink (super annoying)

Is there any way in the world to make a hyperlink usable when the cell is both protected and the "select locked cells" box is unchecked??  Or, does anyone know of any other type of workaround?

thanks!